# Why is this INNER JOIN not working?

Tags: php, sql, database, inner-join

I'm trying to INNER JOIN the 'order' table and the 'customer' table but its not working. The common field is 'cus_id'.  Here is my INNER JOIN code:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
INNER JOIN order ON customer.cus_id = order.cus_id;
```

**'customer' table**
[image: 'customer' table]

**'order' table**[image: 'order' table]

Comment: In what way is it not working? Also, what database is this question related to?

Comment: order is key word of mysql . make it enclosed by back ticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Order** is key word of mysql . make it enclosed by back ticks

```
  SELECT *
  FROM customer
  INNER JOIN `order` ON customer.cus_id = order.cus_id;
```